# Angular Material table Sizing/Scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material table with many columns.  It is wider than the screen.  When I scroll, the table rows extend past the edge of the table container.

See this StackBlitz project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6xdgk  Use the scrollbar at the bottom and you will see the strange formatting.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add

```
.example-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

To the app.component.css to fix the top bar.
The bottom will need a similar styling. You can't use width:100% because it is technically outside the table. So it can not pick up the width automatically.

Answer (score 23):

I hope this will be help full for others to add Horizontal Scrolling to mat-table and column width according to cell content.

```css
.mat-table {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.mat-cell,
.mat-header-cell {
  word-wrap: initial;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-break: unset;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.mat-row,
.mat-header-row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It works perfectly. The accepted answer didn't work form me.

Comment: this saved my day, none of other many answers in questions worked for me

Comment: fantastic snippet!

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can also help others dealing with the width of the mat-table rows.

In this example: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-sticky-complex-flex a min-width with a fixed value in px is set for mat-rows.

To avoid having to do that you can use:

```
.mat-row {
  min-width: max-content;
}
```

This will calculate the content width of the row without having to sum each column width. This will keep as well the style for the mat-row in the whole scrolling area.

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 15

```css
.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.table-responsive table {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

From [Horizontal scroll on overflow of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794211/horizontal-scroll-on-overflow-of-table/48930521#48930521)

This also worked, but columns were squashed together:

```css
.mat-mdc-table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Taken from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-scroll

Answer (score 0):

If you know the widths of your cells then **add them all together** and set that as the width of the table.

And if that sounds obvious, did you think about using calc if they're in mixed units :

[image]

Worked for me.

Note: I set `min-width` so if the table is less than the width of the page it should still work with other flex settings.